# ActionListener is not being called on dynamically created HtmlCommandLink

Tags: jsf-2

I have a dynamically created `HtmlCommandLink` with an `ActionListener`, but when I click on the link, the action listener method is not being called.

Code:

```
   public HtmlPanelGroup getP() {
        p = new HtmlPanelGroup();
        FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HtmlCommandLink l = new HtmlCommandLink();
        l.setTitle("Goto");
        l.setImmediate(true);
        l.addActionListener(new ComponenetListener());
        //new ListenerTest());//new MethodExpressionActionListener(methodExpression) );
        l.setValue("Go");
        p.getChildren().add(l);
        return p;
    }
```

and listener code is

```
  @ManagedBean
  @SessionScoped
  public class ComponenetListener implements ActionListener{

       public ComponenetListener() {
          String s="sridhar";
           }

     @Override
     public void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
         UIComponent eventComponent = event.getComponent();
         System.out.println("test");
         String strEventCompID = eventComponent.getId();
         throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must give all your dynamically created input and command components a fixed ID.

```
l.setId("yourID");
```

You also need to ensure that there's a `<h:form>` (or `UIForm`) component present as tree parent.